# Using a table as a unique dictionary without disregarding 1NF?

Tags: c#, sql, database, dictionary

I have a table Employee, with the parameters {EmployeeId, Name, Age, etc.}. However, I need to give Employees individual rights, for example a Dictionary containing values like ("Back-Up Database", false).

However, adding a Dictionary to the Employee table goes against the 1st Normal Form. I was thinking of creating a new table Function(PK string description, bool allowed), but this way I can't assign unique values for each Employee, right? Because if I link two Employees to the table Function, and change one Function it would affect them both.

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and can't find any satisfying and good solutions. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about add an `EmployeeId` field to the Function table? You can link 2 tables with the `EmployeeId` field.

Comment: Oh wow, didn't think of this at all. Thanks! I think this solves my problem exactly.